# Is it possible to resize fixed dialog boxes that are part of Visual Studio?

Tags: dialog, resize, settings, visual-studio-6

In Visual Studio 6 the project settings dialog box is not resizable. Is there a reason for it to be so?

I know this is a long shot, but any trick to "fix" this problem?

Comment: Reminder to those who have voted to close on this question - programming tools [are on topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and are explicitly mentioned in the FAQ: "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: I feel your pain, even in VS2010 there are still so many unfixed UI gaffs just like that once you scratch the surface. The one that's caused me to ruin a few keyboards is the pre and post build step settings in the project properties Build Events tab. One does wonder what they are thinking about when they design these UI's. Sadly I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

> I know this is a long shot, but any trick to "fix" this problem?

The "trick" is to edit the resources for the executable manually and make the dialog boxes resizable.

But that doesn't actually solve the problem, or someone at Microsoft would surely have done that for one of the many intervening versions of Visual Studio between 6 and 10. In fact, this very thing has been repeatedly suggested on Microsoft Connect and UserVoice (among other places) as a substantial usability problem, and there seems to be general agreement about that fact.

The *real* problem is that you have to write code to get the *controls* on the dialog box to automatically resize when their container (the dialog) is resized. Since that's non-trivial, it hasn't been done yet for any of the new releases of VS. And there's no way to go back and do it on one of the old versions, since editing code in a compiled executable is something I wouldn't recommend to anyone.

It still might happen in a future version of VS, which should be a compelling reason to upgrade for everyone, much less people that are still using VC++ 6, a product released nearly 15 years ago.
Keep your fingers crossed.

As far as adding it to VC++ 6 now, it's simply not possible. Your best hope would be a third-party extension that *replaces* the dialog with a resizable one. It won't be exactly equivalent to the built-in dialog, though, and it'll be very hard to find such add-on utilities now, given their age. You'd probably need to visit a museum.